# ListView always returns the first position

Tags: android, listview

I'm doing an app to help me at school. But, I have a problem: when I want the position (int position) of the listView, it ALWAYS returns the first position, even if I select the third position, for example.

```
public class TestsActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    private List<Map<String, Object>> tests;
    private AlertDialog dialogDelete;
    private int selectedTest;
    private Application dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tests_activity);

        dao = new Application(this);

        android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("My tests");

        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        String[] from = {"subject", "content"};
        int[] to = {R.id.subject, R.id.content};

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listTests(), R.layout.test_list_activity, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        this.dialogDelete = createDialogDelete();
    }

    private List<Map<String, Object>> listTests() {

        tests = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

        List<Test> TestList = dao.listTests();

        for (Test test : TestList) {

            Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            Long id = test.getId();
            String subject = test.getSubject();

            item.put("id", test.getId());

            item.put("subject", subject);

            test.add(item);
        }

        return tests;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Map<String, Object> map = tests.get(position);

        String subject = (String) map.get("subject");
        String msg = "Test of" + subject;

        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        selectedTest = position;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.tests_context_menu, menu);
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        Intent intent;
        String id = String.valueOf(tests.get(selectedTest).get("id"));

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.remove:
                dialogDelete.show();
                break;

            case R.id.edit:
                intent = new Intent(this, NewTestActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constantes.TEST_ID, id);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Intent intent;
        String id = String.valueOf(tests.get(selectedTest).get("id"));

        switch (item) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                tests.remove(selectedTest);
                dao.removeTest(id);
                getListView().invalidateViews();
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                dialogDelete.dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }

    private AlertDialog createDialogDelete() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setMessage(R.string.confirm_delete_test);

        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), (android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener) this);
        builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), (android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener) this);

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        dao.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you mean the position in public void onItemClick method?

Comment: For example, I want to delete a test. So, I get the value of the position and set the variable selectedTest in onItemClick, but i'm getting always the first position

Comment: Where is that code? pls just post it...

Comment: `@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Map<String, Object> map = tests.get(position);

        selectedTest = position;

    }`

Comment: And at onClick(DialogInterface...) : `String id = String.valueOf(tests.get(selectedTest).get("id"));`

Comment: In onItemClick(), do you always get position equal to 0, as what you were saying?

Comment: You call method listarProvas, where is that code? Post that one too, it's all relevant.

Comment: listarProvas = listTests... I forgot when I translated the code. Sorry

Comment: I posted an answer based on your responses. This was not easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Test test : TestList) {

        Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Long id = test.getId();
        String subject = prova.getSubject();

        item.put("id", prova.getId());

        item.put("subject", subject);

        tests.add(item);
    }
```

Try to change from

```
test.add(item);
```

to

```
tests.add(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever call listTests() in you Activity? What it this private method for?

You should call listTests() somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u should use an custom BaseAdapter 
it's help u clearly to create every ceil of listview

```
private class  Simple extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your responses, here are my suggestions.

1) In **listTests**(), change from:

```
test.add(item);
```

TO:

```
tests.add(item);
```

The reason is object **tests** is the ArrayList containing the object test.

2) Since the code depends on the list dao from `List<Test> TestList = dao.listTests();` I want to avoid the list items being unexpectedly removed. So
in `protected void onDestroy()`, remove:

```
dao.close();
```

Comment: Aaah, I discover that the position is working well at on item click. But the global variable selectedTest is not working on other functions